# Can I pass an array into fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, arrays, fromcharcode

I might be asking the wrong question here, so I apologize if the answer is on another thread... but I've looked around to no avail.

in a snippet, why doesn't this work?

```
array = [72,69,76,76,79];
document.write(String.fromCharCode(array));
```

I'm collecting key events in an array and want to be able to write them out as chars when prompted. And though this works:

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79));
```

I can't seem to get it to work when I pass it along as an array. I've also tried to convert the array toString() first, as well array.join(","); to create a comma separated list ...yet nothing. Any ideas? Is there a better way to convert the values I collect in my array into chars?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use the function's `apply()` method...

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGzfY/).

ES6 can use the spread operator...

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(...array));
```

You could also use the array's `reduce()` method, but older IEs do not support it. You could *shim* it, but the `apply()` method is better supported.

```
document.write(array.reduce(function(str, charIndex) {
    return str += String.fromCharCode(charIndex);
}, ''));​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6F8Tk/).

Comment: Take in the account that this trick is potentially dangerous. In case if you will try to construct very long strings this way (e.g. preparing ArrayBuffer for base64 encoding), you will have a range exception.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call a function which an array passed in as its arguments:

```
array = [72,69,76,76,79];
document.write(String.fromCharCode.apply(String, array));
```

Comment: @alex Yeah, I don't think it really matters what this is, I picked `String` because it's what all the cool kids are doing.

Comment: I prefer: `String.fromCharCode.apply(window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, array)`

Comment: fantastic, this also wrx :) thnx!

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. I wrote that comment when you forgot it. All good now :)

Comment: @alex Oh I see haha. Darn, I thought I was too fast for anyone to see my mistake haha

Answer (score 3):

If you use `.apply()` to call the `fromCharCode()` function, you can pass it an array that will be converted into arguments for the function like this:

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode.apply(this, array));
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pfLLZ/

Comment: @Nick Yeah, they're not a bad car.

Answer (score 1):

The method is more meant to be  used like this:

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79));
```

You're passing in an array when the method expects multiple parameters as a list.

Comment: This can get messy for large strings

Comment: They have a hard limit of 65536 entries in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In new version of javascript, you can use [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const array = [72,69,76,76,79];
document.write(String.fromCharCode(...array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a loop as follows

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       document.write(String.fromCharCode(array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's 2 ways that I would do it:

```js
var arr=[119,119,119,46,87,72,65,75,46,99,111,109];
document.write(eval('String.fromCharCode('+arr+')'));

document.write('<hr>');

var arr='119,119,119,46,87,72,65,75,46,99,111,109';
document.write(eval('String.fromCharCode('+arr+')'));
```

Comment: Depending on the implicit conversion of the array to a string is not immediately visible, sadly.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a function:

```js
var unCharCode = function(x) {
  return this["eval"]("String['fromCharCode'](" + x + ")");
};

document.write(unCharCode([ 119, 119, 119, 46, 87, 72, 65, 75, 46, 99, 111, 109 ]));

document.write("<hr>");

document.write(unCharCode("119,119,119,46,87,72,65,75,46,99,111,109"));
```

Comment: Why `eval` using bracket notation? Why `eval` at all?