# String.fromCharCode gives no result javaScript

Tags: javascript, fromcharcode

after running code i get no result in window. and i cant find problem
result have to be string created from charCode.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var te = [];
  var i = 0;
  var a = 0;
  var newte = [];

  while (i < str.length) {
    te[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    i++;
  }
  while (a != te.length) {
    if (te[a] < 65) {
      newte[a] = te[a] + 13;
    } else
      newte[a] = te[a];
    a++;
  }

  var mystring = String.fromCharCode(newte);


  return mystring;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: You do nothing with the returned value - what do you expect?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(newte);` probably doesn't do what you expect either

Comment: could you explain me what i miss? i try`ed several different scenarios and i always getting error or nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass an array into fromCharCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936490/can-i-pass-an-array-into-fromcharcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `String.fromCharCode` expects you to pass each number as an individual argument. In your code sample, you are passing an array as a single argument, which won't work.

Try using the `apply()` method instead, which will allow you to pass an array, and it will convert that into multiple individual arguments:

```
var mystring = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, newte);
```

Comment: `.call` does not take an array in this way, that's `.apply`.

Comment: Oops, yeah no you're totally right. Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) is not defined to operate on an array.

Try like this:

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var result = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + 1;
    
    if (charCode < 65) {
      charCode += 13;
    }
    
    result += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

**NOTE:** I copied your logic for the character substitution, but [it doesn't seem correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

Comment: yea, i found that i do not get result as i expected :) going to work with it more.