# Why String.fromCharCode() does not work with variable as parameter?

Tags: javascript, fromcharcode

I noticed that `String.fromCharCode()` does not work with a variable as parameter.

Here is some sample code:

```js
var x = atob('ODAsNjUsODMsODMsODcsNzksODIsNjgsOTUsNDgsNDk=');
console.log('\''+x.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '\',\'')+'\'');
console.log(String.fromCharCode('\'' + x.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '\',\'') + '\''));
```

Now this would evaluate to

```
'80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49'
```

which is a correct parameter chain for `String.fromCharCode()`
because this works:

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode('80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49'));
```

Why doesn't it accept the variable as parameter?

Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: You're passing very different things to `fromCharCode`.

Comment: You are actually doing: `console.log(String.fromCharCode(['80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49']));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
var x = atob('ODAsNjUsODMsODMsODcsNzksODIsNjgsOTUsNDgsNDk=');
console.log(String.fromCharCode('\'' + x.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '\',\'') + '\''));
```

`'\''+x.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '\',\'')+'\''` produces a string. It’s just a text that says `'80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49'`. If you pass this string to `String.fromCharCode`... definitely not what you wanted. How is JavaScript supposed to convert this to *one* number?

```
String.fromCharCode('80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49')
```

Here you pass multiple arguments. Multiple strings. And each of them can easily be converted into a number.

What you can do is simply split the string at `,` and then splat the resulting array: (ECMAScript 6)

```
String.fromCharCode(...x.split(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass an array tho:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, ['80','65','83','83','87','79','82','68','95','48','49'])
```

Here is a similar.. the same question:

[Can I pass an array into fromCharCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936490/can-i-pass-an-array-into-fromcharcode)