# Apply doesn't work with fromCharCode - javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to pass an array of number to the method String.fromCharCode(), I read another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936490/can-i-pass-an-array-into-fromcharcode) and tried to chain apply after fromCharCode, but it doesn't work for me. Here's the code:

```
function rot13(str) {
  var reStr = "";
  var asciiCodedArr = [70,82,69,69,32,67,79,68,69,32,67,65,77,80];
  reStr = String.fromCharCode().apply(null, asciiCodedArr);
  return reStr;
}

rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

And it yells back at me:

```
TypeError: String.fromCharCode(...).apply is not a function
```

Where did I mess up ?

Comment: You are calling apply on the invocation of the function instead of the function. Use: `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, asciiCodedArr);`

Comment: `apply` is a property of functions; you're trying to call it on the _result_ of the `fromCharCode` function. Try `String.fromCharCode.apply` without the parens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `()` after `fromCharCode`, and you're golden.

Essentially, you were trying to find an `apply` method on the *result* of calling `fromCharCode` (which is a string and thus does not have methods from `Function.prototype`) instead of on the function `fromCharCode` itself.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var reStr = "";
  var asciiCodedArr = [70, 82, 69, 69, 32, 67, 79, 68, 69, 32, 67, 65, 77, 80];
  reStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, asciiCodedArr);
  return reStr;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Comment: The explanation really help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()`

```
 reStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, asciiCodedArr);
```

NOT

```
 reStr = String.fromCharCode().apply(null, asciiCodedArr);
```